# Relocating AspectJ packages in a Java agent

Tags: java, aspectj, javaagents

I'm using AspectJ to monitor field access and field modify. I have a gradle project that compiles the two aspects and package that jar together with the aspectjrt and aspectjweaver in a shaded jar using gradle shadow plugin.
the agent is still org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.Agent.
everything works fine, but when i try to relocate the aspectj packages I get an error.

The shadow plugin configuration is:

```
shadowJar {
    relocate 'org.aspectj', 'shadow.org.aspectj'
    relocate 'aj.org.objectweb.asm', 'shadow.aj.org.objectweb.asm'
}
```

The manifest :

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes("Premain-Class": "shadow.org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.Agent",
                "Can-Redefine-Classes": true,
                "Can-Retransform-Classes":true)
    }
}
```

This is the decompiled aspect class so it seems correct:

```
package com.vfunction.singletonanalysis;

import shadow.org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import shadow.org.aspectj.lang.NoAspectBoundException;
import shadow.org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import shadow.org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

@Aspect
public class StaticFieldBeforeAccessAspect extends AbstractFieldAccessAspect {
    public StaticFieldBeforeAccessAspect() {
    }

    @Before("callAt()")
    public void before(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        this.printJoinPoint(joinPoint);
    }

    public static StaticFieldBeforeAccessAspect aspectOf() {
        if (ajc$perSingletonInstance == null) {
            throw new NoAspectBoundException("com.vfunction.singletonanalysis.StaticFieldBeforeAccessAspect", ajc$initFailureCause);
        } else {
            return ajc$perSingletonInstance;
        }
    }

    public static boolean hasAspect() {
        return ajc$perSingletonInstance != null;
    }

    static {
        try {
            ajc$postClinit();
        } catch (Throwable var1) {
            ajc$initFailureCause = var1;
        }

    }
}
```

But I still get an error when trying to run a test program saying the the type found is not an aspect:

```
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] info AspectJ Weaver Version 1.8.12 built on Friday Oct 20, 2017 at 21:58:11 GMT
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] info register classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] info using configuration file:***/workspace/singleton-analysis/agent/build/libs/agent-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-all.jar!/META-INF/aop.xml
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] info register aspect com.vfunction.singletonanalysis.StaticFieldModifyAspect
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] error The specified aspect 'com.vfunction.singletonanalysis.StaticFieldModifyAspect' cannot be found
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] info register aspect com.vfunction.singletonanalysis.StaticFieldAccessAspect
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] error The specified aspect 'com.vfunction.singletonanalysis.StaticFieldAccessAspect' cannot be found
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] info register aspect com.vfunction.singletonanalysis.StaticFieldBeforeAccessAspect
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] error Cannot register 'com.vfunction.singletonanalysis.StaticFieldBeforeAccessAspect' because the type found with that name is not an aspect
```

Comment: At what time happens what? Is it loadtime or compile time weaving? When does this shadowing happen?

Comment: @TamasRev , its load time weaving. relocation happens at build time using gradle when packaging the agent jar.

Answer (score 1):

Check contents of `aop.xml` inside the shaded jar.
Is the aspect class name shadowed? I would suspect that it's not given the error message.

[As mentioned in documentation](http://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/#controlling_jar_content_merging), you can make Shadow plugin transform XML files like this:

```
shadowJar {
    tranform(XmlAppendingTransformer.class) {
        resource = 'aop.xml'
    }
}
```

Comment: does it work without shadowing? It looks like your exception originates from here https://github.com/eclipse/org.aspectj/blob/8dda42d0272eb4fdc157282880caf915a9e33ea1/weaver/src/org/aspectj/weaver/bcel/BcelWeaver.java#L223

I would try attaching a debugger and stepping through the code. Looking at implementations of `isAspect` method I see some suspicious things like this:
https://github.com/eclipse/org.aspectj/blob/03752862ba3bc6ef132195673903dcf9109e8b93/org.aspectj.ajdt.core/src/org/aspectj/ajdt/internal/compiler/lookup/EclipseSourceType.java#L176

Comment: Also try setting System property "-Dorg.aspectj.tracing.enabled=true" to enable AspectJ tracing. That way you'll get more insight into what's going on. see https://github.com/eclipse/org.aspectj/blob/eb5b2857783d3060a5a3188a3811f5cbb8f81aa5/org.aspectj.matcher/src/org/aspectj/weaver/tools/DefaultTraceFactory.java#L20

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's the issue. I do not relocate my aspect classes, only the dependencies like aspectj library. so my aspect class looks like that:

```
import com.vfunction.jni.Callbacks;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import vshadow.org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import vshadow.org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import vshadow.org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import vshadow.org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

@Aspect
public class StaticFieldBeforeModifyAspect extends AbstractFieldAccessAspect
```

as you see it imports  vshadow.org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect , that class exists.
the issue is that the aspectjweaver code checks if a class is a valid aspect by inspecting if the class has an org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect annotation, but it doesn't ,it has a vshadow.org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect annotation.
the aspectjweaver checks for the annotation using a string constant.
it happens in org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver#addLibraryAspect
and the constant is used like that for example:

```
public final static UnresolvedType ASPECT_ANNOTATION = UnresolvedType.forSignature("Lorg/aspectj/lang/annotation/Aspect;")
```

and the shadow plugin does not relocate that.

I'm pretty sure that's the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can try excluding `Aspect` annotation from shadowing:

```
shadowJar {
   relocate('org.aspectj', 'shadow.org.aspectj') {
       exclude 'org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect'
   }
}
```

see http://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/#relocating_packages

Another hacky option is to write your own [`Transformer`](http://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/api/com/github/jengelman/gradle/plugins/shadow/transformers/Transformer.html) that will search and replace `"Lorg/aspectj/lang/annotation/Aspect;"` with shadowed version.

see http://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/#controlling_jar_content_merging

Comment: my answer to your suggestion is above, couldn't write it as comment.